# how to use ObjectId inside $in query in MongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have the following query in MongoDB

```
$this->createQueryBuilder()
            ->field('actor')->in($actorIdArray)
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute();
```

where the field actor is an object reference with annotation

```
@MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="User", simple=true)
```

which means it will store the object Id instead of the full reference.

When $actorIdArray is an array of id with the form

```
["5706cb39821b166d3931f34f", "56015f7d4f8bd90b769e6e75"]
```

the query does not return nothing, which is the expected since the filed actor contains object id.

However, if I build the array this way

```
[new MongoId("5706cb39821b166d3931f34f"), new MongoId("56015f7d4f8bd90b769e6e75")]
```

it doesn't work either, which is quite surprising for me.

The log shows the query is made

```
{ "actor": {"$in":[{"$id":"5706cb39821b166d3931f34f"},{"$id":"56015f7d4f8bd90b769e6e75"}]}}
```

and I think it should be something like this

```
{ "actor": {"$in":[ObjectId("5706cb39821b166d3931f34f"),ObjectId("56015f7d4f8bd90b769e6e75"]}}
```

Not sure if I am doing something wrong, 
any ideas?

Comment: it must be an array of Documents from the ODM.

Comment: If you want to avoid the object load, use a reference http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/mongodb_odm/1.0/class-Doctrine.ODM.MongoDB.DocumentManager.html#_getReference

Comment: @Alsatian this query works if I execute it from the console

{ "actor": {"$in":[ObjectId("5706cb39821b166d3931f34f"),ObjectId("56015f7d4f8bd90b769e6e75"]}}

so there is no need of use an array of documents.

Comment: Doctrine serialize wyour array. When your array contains Documents it will convert them to ObjectId(...). Please try it.

Comment: Anyway I don't have the document really, so if I do what you propose I will need to make one query for each id inside $in (which can be hundreds of items). I just need to make the query with doctrine as I do it in console (by using only id's). Hope you @Alsatian can help me with this

Comment: BTW I only have ids because it comes from cache where the author's following id's are stored

Comment: Read my second comment again :). I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in code source of `Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Query\Builder` -> `references` method:

```
public function references(object $document) : self
    {
        $this->requiresCurrentField();
        $mapping   = $this->getReferenceMapping();
        $reference = $this->dm->createReference($document, $mapping);
        $storeAs   = $mapping['storeAs'] ?? null;
        $keys      = [];

        switch ($storeAs) {
            case ClassMetadata::REFERENCE_STORE_AS_ID:
                $this->query[$mapping['name']] = $reference;

                return $this;
            .....

        return $this;
    }
```

You must know how the reference is built. Usually, this is by `$id`.

Use `actor.$id` as the field name:

```
$dm = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager'):

$documents = array();
foreach($actorIdArray as $id){
    $documents[] = new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId($id);
}

$this->createQueryBuilder()
            ->field('actor.$id')->in($documents)
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

Doctrine wants your array to be an array of documents.

You can load [document references](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/mongodb_odm/1.0/class-Doctrine.ODM.MongoDB.DocumentManager.html#_getReference) without query.

```
$dm = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager'):

$documents = array();
foreach($actorIdArray as $id){
    $documents[] = $dm->getReference('AppBundle:Actor',$id); // <- this is the key
}

$this->createQueryBuilder()
            ->field('actor')->in($documents)
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute();
```

Comment: It does not work :( this is what $dm->getReference returns

{
    "__initializer__": {},
    "__cloner__": {},
    "__isInitialized__": false
  }